# My plugin code slows down Eclipse, what could I improve?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a ITextViewer object and from that the StyledText widget in which Eclipse displays code. I want to hihglight one single line that is defined by the line number. Therefore I added a LineBackgroundListener to the StyledText object an wrote the following code:

```
private class HighlightLine implements LineBackgroundListener {

        @Override
        public void lineGetBackground(LineBackgroundEvent event) {
            if (lineToHighlight != -1) {
                int line = ((StyledText) event.widget).getLineAtOffset(event.lineOffset);
                if (line == lineToHighlight) {
                    event.lineBackground = styledText.getSelectionBackground();
                } else if (line == previousLineToHighlight) {
                    event.lineBackground = styledText.getBackground();
                }
                styledText.redraw();
                styledText.update();
            }
        }

    }
```

This work more or less fine, but the problem is, it very much slows down Eclipse. It's probably the case because it has to update the Widget very often and that's not optimal. However, I couldn't think of another way to to it after a lot of trials. Any idea?

Comment: Try to redraw and update only on change line color.

Comment: @WidWing Good idea, but I didn't found a way to find out if the line color has changed.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need these (expensive) calls:

```
styledText.redraw();
styledText.update();
```

`lineGetBackground` is called during the draw line operation so it does not need a redraw or update.

Note: If the `StyledText` control has any `StyleRange` ranges they may override the background.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The problem is, when I remove the redraw method, the line coloring is not visible anymore.

Comment: That is probably because StyleRange is in use, your calls are messing with that (and might well behave differently on other platforms). As I said in your previous question if the editor is using the full Eclipse presentation system you have to find a way to hook in to that.